# my mui dataTable in not responsive yet iam using FLEX 1;

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID',  },
    {
      field: 'moduleName',
      headerName: 'Module Name',
      flex: 1,
      editable: false,
      sortable: false,
      filter: false,
      hideable: false
    },
    {
      field: 'moduleCode',
      headerName: 'Module Code',
      flex:1,
      align: "left",
      editable: false,
      sortable: false,
    },
    {
      field: 'moduleType',
      headerName: 'Module Type',
      type: 'number',
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      editable: false,
      align: "left",
      headerAlign: 'left'
    },
    {
      field: 'yearOfStudy',
      headerName: 'Year of Study',
      type: 'number',
      flrx: 1,
      sortable: false,
      editable: false,
      align: "left",
      headerAlign: 'left'
    },
    {
      field: 'program',
      headerName: 'program',
      type: 'number',
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      editable: false,
      align: "left",
      headerAlign: 'left'
    },
    {
      field: 'programCode',
      headerName: 'Program Code',
      type: 'number',
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      editable: false,
      align: "left",
      headerAlign: 'left'
    },
   
  ];
```

this is how it looks on the pc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRnAz.png)

now this is on mobile it is not responsive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUpzf.png) this mobile it is not responsive

mui datagrid by setting columns to

flex it is not responsive on mobiles phones it is just truncating the text instead of flex

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
      <Box
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
          display:"table",
          tableLayout:"fixed",
        }}
      >
        <DataGrid
          className="responsive-data-grid"
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          initialState={{
            pagination: {
              paginationModel: {
                pageSize: 5,
              },
            },
          }}
          pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          disableRowSelectionOnClick
        />
      </Box>
```